# How to display decimal place in pgfplotstable when it is 0 (zero)?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

Using pgfplotstable I plot a table of data which has more decimal places than 1, however, I just want to display 1 decimal place so I am using `precision=1`, which works well, except for in cases where the decimal place is a 0. It does not display 14.0 but only 14 although I said `precision=1`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
This is what I get from pgfplotstable:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=\\,precision=1,column type={r}
    ]{
    a,     b,     c\\
17.82,  7.51,  7.62\\
17.02, 14.02, 12.01\\
19.43,  6.03,  4.52\\
18.03,  7.41,  6.81\\
}

This is what I want:

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
   a&   b&    c\\
17.8& 7.5&  7.6\\
17.0&14.0& 12.0\\
19.4& 6.0&  4.5\\
18.0& 7.4&  6.8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How to tell pgfplotstable to print the .0?

Comment: `fixed zerofill`

Comment: @Symbol1 an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots), and [pgfplotstable](/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable) use the same number-printing system and one can find a elaborated explanation in both [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) and [pgfplotstable](/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable)'s documents.

- `/pgf/number format/fixed` rounds the number to a fixed number of digits after the period, discarding any trailing zeros.

  > 4.57     0     0.1     24,415.98     123,456.12
- `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill={⟨boolean⟩}` enables or disables zero filling for any number drawn in fixed point format.

  > 4.57     0.00     0.10     24,415.98     123,456.12
- `/pgf/number format/sci` configures `\pgfmathprintnumber` to display numbers in scientific format, that means sign, mantissa and exponent (base 10). The mantissa is rounded to the desired precision (or sci precision, see below).

  > 4.57·10<sup>0</sup>     5·10<sup>-4</sup>     1·10<sup>-1</sup>     2.44·10<sup>4</sup>     1.23·10<sup>5</sup>
- `/pgf/number format/sci zerofill={⟨boolean⟩}` enables or disables zero filling for any number drawn in scientific format.

  > 4.57·10<sup>0</sup>     5.00·10<sup>-4</sup>     1.00·10<sup>-1</sup>     2.44·10<sup>4</sup>     1.23·10<sup>5</sup>
- `/pgf/number format/zerofill={⟨boolean⟩}` sets both `fixed zerofill` and `sci zerofill` at once.

Read the document for more options.

For your case, writing

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=\\,precision=1,
                      fixed zerofill, column type={r}]
```

will do the job.